# How can I trigger a method in the backing code when an entry field value is changed?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application where a Xamarin Entry field is used to allow a number to be entered. Here is what I coded:

```
<Entry 
   Keyboard="Numeric" 
   x:Name="dBtnPts"
   VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
   TextColor="Gray" Completed="dBtnPtsChanged"
   WidthRequest="55"/>



void dBtnPtsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   App.DB.UpdateStringSetting(Settings.ABtnPoints, ((Entry)sender).Text);
}
```

When I put a break point inside the dBtnPtsChanged method it's never called.

Can someone point me to where I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`completed` occurs when you click the done button.

It can be triggerd on the sumilator  on PC when we click the `Enter` on the keyboard, However , When runs on the real device,no button like **Done** or **Return** in the keyboard in Xamarin.forms.

So as a temporary solution , we can add the tap event to the entry's parent layout.

Code in XMAL:

```
<StackLayout >
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped = "Handle_Tapped" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

    <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" 
           x:Name="dBtnPts"
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="End"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
           TextColor="Gray" 
           Completed = "Handle_Completed"
           WidthRequest="55"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    App.DB.UpdateStringSetting(Settings.ABtnPoints, ((Entry)dBtnPts).Text);
}
```

### Update:

As SharadaGururaj suggested, a better and simple way is assign the event `Unfocused` of Entry ,and operate the db inside it. Of course we can take the solution in SharadaGururaj's Answer, it is more Controllable and flexible.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - but don't you think the `Handle_Tapped` will be called every-time page was tapped, regardless of whether there was any change in `Entry` or not? Also, this will be a bigger problem if we have multiple `Entry` controls on same page. No?

Comment: @SharadaGururaj Yes,you are right, it will invoke every time when we tap the page, but as I said above, the event `Completed` will never be triggered on the device , so it is no need to expand the Entry , just need to assign the event `Unfocused` and do the db action inside it.

Comment: Agreed, just handling `Unfocused` event might work; but `Unfocused` event, on it's own, won't be able to convey whether the text changed or not, and will still end up causing unnecessary DB action(s). Anyway, just wanted to share my assessment with you. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `Entry` to invoke event only when text update is complete; for e.g.:

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{
    public event EventHandler TextUpdated;

    private bool _isDirty = false;
    public CustomEntry()
    {
        Completed += CustomEntry_Completed;
        Unfocused += CustomEntry_Unfocused;
        TextChanged += CustomEntry_TextChanged;
    }

    private void CustomEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    private void CustomEntry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDirty)
        {
            _isDirty = false;
            TextUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void CustomEntry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDirty)
        {
            _isDirty = false;
            TextUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And sample usage would look like:

```
<local:CustomEntry 
  Keyboard="Numeric" 
  x:Name="dBtnPts"
  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" 
  HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
  TextColor="Gray" TextUpdated="dBtnPtsChanged"
  WidthRequest="55"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `completed` event is only called whenever the user presses the return button. For example, the blue Done button on the iOS soft keyboard.

You probably want to look at the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: For the numeric entry I don't see a Done button appear.  The only way I can clear the screen is by clicking another part of the screen and then I see the new entry stay in the window.

Comment: The problem I have with TextChanged is that it gets triggered on every press of the numbers.  So if I enter 123 as the number it would get triggered (and update the database) three times.

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried hitting the actual return key on your keyboard? Anyhow, I don't think this will be a solution for you. You're probably looking for some event that triggers when the focus is lost. You will need a custom renderer for that. Although that is dangerous as well. What if the user leaves the screen without ever losing focus.

Comment: The trigger for each digit, could be prevented by implementing some timeout. If another digit is pressed within a certain timeframe, cancel the timeout that will fire the DB update.